# Parameters in requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

So I'm trying to learn python so I can work with an api.  The tutorial I was using was using python 2 and urllib.  I'm running python 3.6, so it wasn't working.  So I decided to try and learn about requests.  I'm having a little bit of trouble converting from urllib to requests.

```
import requests
import json

parameters = {"apikey": "mykey", "queries": "SN74S74N"}

response = requests.get("http://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match", params = 
parameters)
data = response.json()


#print(type(data))
print(data)
```

The error I get when I run this is

```
{'message': 'JSON decode error: SN74S74N', '__class__': 'ClientErrorResponse'}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  But I think it might be because my parameters aren't set up right.  Is requests capable of doing the same thing they have in the documentation? https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/rest-api#endpoints-parts-match

Sorry this is vague, I just started learning python and apis.  Will be around to further clarify any questions.

Comment: According to the documentation https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/rest-api#endpoints-parts-match, the value of `queries=` shouldn't be a simple string like `SN74S74N`.

Comment: So a quick look at the octopart API docs make it look like this is an error their API is returning saying your `queries` value isn't in the format they expect. Requests is doing what it should, but you'll need to work on formatting the query.

Comment: The documentation (https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/overview) seems to indicate the "queries" parameter should be a list of dictionaries, not a string.  Like in their Python example: `queries = [
    {'mpn': 'SN74S74N',
     'reference': 'line1'},
    {'sku': '67K1122',
     'reference': 'line2'},
    {'mpn_or_sku': 'SN74S74N',
     'reference': 'line3'},
    {'brand': 'Texas Instruments',
     'mpn': 'SN74S74N',
     'reference': 'line4'}
    ]´

Comment: Basically, follow their tutorial as far as building the `queries` list of dicts, serialize it into json, then pass that in as part of your dict - `parameters = {"apikey": "mykey", "queries": json.dumps(queries)}`. `requests` handles the URI escaping but you still need to give it json.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the docs you provided for the API it looks like your parameters aren't structured how the API requires it.

Under the examples section, it shows the `queries` sent with the request as:

```
queries = [
    {'mpn': 'SN74S74N',
     'reference': 'line1'},
    {'sku': '67K1122',
     'reference': 'line2'}
]
```

So for your example you need:

```
queries = [
    {'mpn': 'SN74S74N',
     'reference': reference goes here}
]
```

and use the request as you have in your code.

[link to the docs](https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/rest-api#endpoints-parts-match)